# How can I use Enter to send from a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-keyboard, instant-messaging

I just purchased a [Logitech K760 Wireless keyboard](http://amzn.to/KHGuV4) for my Nexus 4.  I have the keyboard paired properly to my phone, but I am unable to *send* from the keyboard, when sending IMs via Facebook, Skype, etc.

I also have SwiftKey installed, and have tried using both SwiftKey and the default Google Keyboard, and both behave the same way.

Is there a configuration option, or add-on app I can use to control how this works?  My ideal configuration would have <kbd>ENTER</kbd> send, and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> (or similar) insert a newline.  But I would also be willing to map the *send* function to one of the F-keys or something else, if that's what I must do.

I am using Android 4.4.2.

Comment: It does work on Google Talk so it's the problem which needs to be fixed by facebook in their messenger app.

Comment: `control` + `enter` works for me in my Logitech keyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behaviour depends on the application you use, and so, on the way developer(s) programmed their applications.

The application may provide an option to use <kbd>enter</kbd> as send, but if it doesn't, then I think you can't do much about this...

Comment: So I guess you're saying there's generic "send" API call, and thus no (standard) way to write a third party app that could bind a key to "send" in every app?

Comment: @Flimzy, I think it might be more an event than an API Call, but that's the right idea.

Answer (score 12):

Press the TAB/right arrow key until the send button of the app is selected. Then hit ENTER. That works for me.

Often, the TAB/right arrow key only needs to pressed once or twice before the send key can be activated using ENTER. However, I think this would depend on the graphical user interface of the app.

Comment: TAB + ENTER worked for me

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one should be an accepted answer.

Comment: TAB x 2 was good for me (emoji button is first TAB). This was a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [External Keyboard Helper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper&hl=en_GB)? That lets you make customised keymaps: I use it to kill the caps lock key on my Microsoft Wedge keyboard. But if the application does recognise any keystroke as "send" then EKH will let you map it to the key of your choice.

Answer (score -1):

I have Swiftkey and Android 4.4. The following works for me:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.